# How to connect Z39.50 with YAZ client in JAVA?

Tags: java, z39.50

My requirement is to connect to Z39.50 server from Java code. For connecting to Z39.50 server, I used YAZ client for Windows System which connects to the server and gives the response in MARC/XML format. There is command prompt which takes command and give us the response.

Now, I need to write a Java program(Servlet) to utilize this YAZ client and get these response.

Answer (score 0):

I got solution for it. I used yaz4j.jar to connect with Z39.50 server.